# How to ignore Spotlight index for a volume contain another macOS

Tags: external-disk, spotlight, multi-boot

- Volume A: macOS A
- Volume B: macOS B

How can I ignore Spotlight index of Volume B when using macOS A, while keeping index data and use index when switching to macOS B.

Answer (score 4):

1. Launch System Preferences
2. Select Spotlight
3. Select the Privacy tab
4. Add the tab of the volume that should not be searched (NOT the one you've booted from)
5. Wait a minute - ensure the change gets written to disk
6. Reboot

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this will also disable (and clear) spotlight index when I switch to macOS B. That's not what I want. Maybe I have to use something alternative to Spotlight like Alfred.